# 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/ не заходит

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Захожу по адресу `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/` все заходит но пишет это :

Добро пожаловать в phpMyAdmin

Ошибка
Ответ MySQL: Документация

Соединение невозможно! Неверные настройки.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): ��������� �� �����������, �.�.
>   ������ ������� ������ ������ �� ���������.  Ошибка при указании
>   соединения для controluser в конфигурации.  mysqli_real_connect():
>   (HY000/2002): ��������� �� �����������, �.�. ������ ������� ������
>   ������ �� ���������.

phpMyAdmin не смог установить соединение с сервером MySQL. Проверьте хост, имя пользователя и пароль установленные в конфигурационном файле `config.inc.php` и удостоверьтесь, что они соответствуют данным полученным от администратора сервера MySQL.

Повторить попытку соединения

Comment: настройте логин и пароль в pma для базы данных. Ну вам собственно всё написали.

Comment: спс за ответ....